# Bound for sum of iid Bernoulli distributions

Tags: moment-generating-functions, bernoulli-distribution

Consider $X$ to be the sum of $n$ iid Bernoulli distribution with $p$. I'd like to show that $\forall t > 0$,
$$
\Pr(X > (1+t) n p) < \left(\frac{e^t}{(1+t)^{1+t}} \right)^{np}
.$$

What I have is:
Consider any $t > 0$, and let $X_i$ to be  $i$-th Bernoulli
\begin{align*}
    \Pr(X > (1 + t) np) &= \Pr(e^{t X} > e^{t (1 + t) np}) \\
                        &< \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{t X}]}{e^{t ( 1+ t) np}} & (\text{Markov})\\
                        &= \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{t X_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot e^{tX_n} ]}{e^{t ( 1+ t) np}} \\
                        &= \frac{(1 - p + p e^{t})^{n}}{e^{t ( 1+ t) np}} & (X_i\text{ are iid})
,\end{align*}
where the last line uses the moment generating function (mgf) of $X_i$ (Bernoulli variable), the reason why I use mgf is that otherwise, I can not think of any way to introduce exponential in the RHS of the bound.

But I can proceed no further. Is there any key step I am missing? I really appreciate any hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is called [Chernoff's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound). The result actually holds more generally when the Bernoulli random variables are not identically distributed (independence is an important assumption though). For a proof, see pages 3 and 4 of [this](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Esling/MATH-SHU-236-2020-SPRING/MATH-SHU-236-Lecture-17-18-Concentration.pdf) set of lecture notes. (I can add the details here if necessary.) Note that in their proof the Bernoulli's are not identically distributed, but in the i.i.d. case we have $\mu=\mathbb{E}X=np$.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even realize this is a famous inequality. Learnt something today!

Comment: @dragon_and_dracula The result first appeared in this paper by Herman Chernoff: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2236576.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Aceb89ce2e41f6c6b8b3265ff3be99be1&ab_segments=&origin=&acceptTC=1. Also see this paper by Wassily Hoeffding: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2282952.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A694715e8ad502cd2d7ecd72bff23cdba&ab_segments=&origin=.